# How to get only special field data firebase realtime database react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing react native project using firebase as backend. And I am using firebase realtime database
for saving user information now. I want to get only special field from realtime database. For example, I want to get only user information that email is "devsmith@gmail.com" like following image.
Please help me.
Thanks.

[image: firebase data structure]

Answer (score 0):

You should use @react-native-firebase/database to get your user's data

(doc in Realtime Database section => https://rnfirebase.io)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [react native firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage)

The specific answer is in the [Query section](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#querying):

You will have to use the where operator like so :

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

// ...

firestore()
  .collection('user')
  // Filter results
  .where('email', '==', 'devsmith@gmail.com')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    /* ...do what you want with this querySnapshot */
  }
```